# while submitting post from admin it gives me something like this Select a valid choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, admin

I am trying to give posts category choices , everything works fine but if I add posts from admin panel I get error something like this

> Select a valid choice. SSC is not one of the available choices.
>
> this is my Posts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
# Create your models here.


CATEGORIES = (
        ('SSC', 'SSCQUESTION'),
        ('CAT', 'CATQUESTION'),
    )


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name="Title" )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Updated at")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    file_upload = models.FileField(null= True, blank=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf'])])
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null= True,verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE,choices = CATEGORIES)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    
    # class Meta:
    #     verbose_name = "Post"
    #     verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
    #     ordering = ['-created_at']


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In admin panel this gives error like this

[image: post-error]

Comment: category is a foreign key, why did you have to give choices to it? The admin panel is supposed to populate the categories in that dropdown and choose the id of the selected category and store into the field category.

Comment: I though it would be good to have choices in dropdown and admin can simply select it.I don't know better way. Can you help me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove choices

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null= True,verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Go to the Category table in the admin panel and create some categories there.. Those categories will now be populated in the dropdown in the Post creation page

Comment: You need to register the Category model in the admin.py file of your app to see it in the admin panel